# How to integrate IF FUNCTION (Excel) in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, function

I have an excel sheet with some data and I want to create a new column (if possible at position BA(excel column)) that works as an excel function IF. For example, for row 2 it will be:

1. `=IF(AO2<=0,0,IF(AO2<50000,1,0))`

And for row 3 it will change the number for the corresponding row. Please, help it integrate into python and those functions too:

2. `=IF(AND(BA2=1,AP2>0),1,0)` Updating BA and AP columns for corresponding row.
3. `=IF(BB2=1,AO2,0)` Updating BB and AO for corresponding row.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, show your code - [mre] and explain what problem you cannot solve.

Comment: @buran hi, not really sure if additional information is needed because I just need a python version of the IF statement in excel - the problem itself is much bigger and I just need this part only (with IF). Maybe I do not understand what you are asking for? Please, clarify if so

Comment: Show what have you tried so far to implement what you ask for. There is no python code in your question.

Comment: @buran that is the whole point? I am asking to help to write a code in python

Comment: This is not free code writing service.

Comment: @buran it isn't. and I am not asking to solve the problem, just specific 2-3 lines because I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If u looking for the python version I recommend numpy.where()

check the doc reference:
[enter link description here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)